# Tags in Google Ngrams dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, nlp, n-gram, part-of-speech

**tl;dr** : I can't find a comprehensive list of all tags used in [Google Grams Dataset](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) besides [that one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info) which only includes PoS tags and `_START_`, `_ROOT_` and `_END_`.

What do tokens like `,_.`, `._.`, `_._` mean ? Given their frequencies -- see below -- I'd strongly assume they're **tags** (they can't be proper tokens).

---

**Context :**
I am trying to extract information from Google's n-grams dataset and have troubles understanding some of their tags, and how to take them into account.

Ultimately, I would like to approximate how likely a word will follow another one.
For example, calculating how likely the token `protection` will follow `equal` would roughly mean calculating `count("equal protection") / count("equal *")` where `*` is the wildcard : any 1gram in the corpus.

The tricky part is calculating that `count("equal *")`.
Indeed, for example, the bi-gram `equal to` accounts many times in the Google n-grams dataset :

- as `equal to`,
- as `equal to_PRT` (disambiguated PoS version)
- as `equal _PRT_` (aggregated for all PRT i.e. particles that might follow `equal`).

As shows when I compute this on pyspark :

```
>>> total = ggrams.filter(ggrams.ngram.startswith("equal ")).groupby("ngram") \
             .sum("match_count")

>>> total.sort("sum(match_count)", ascending=False).show(n=15)

+------------+----------------+  
|       ngram|sum(match_count)|  
+------------+----------------+  
|equal _NOUN_|        20130934|  
| equal _PRT_|        16620727|  
|    equal to|        16598291|  
|equal to_PRT|        16598291|  
|   equal _._|         5119672|  
| equal _ADP_|         3037747|  
|     equal ,|         2276119|  
|   equal ,_.|         2276119|  
|    equal in|         1682835|  
|equal in_ADP|         1682176|  
|     equal .|         1628257|  
|   equal ._.|         1628257|  
|equal _CONJ_|         1363739|  
|    ...     |             ...|
```

So to avoid accounting the same bigram multiple times, my idea was to rather just sum all counts for all patterns like `"equal <POS>"` where `<POS>` is in the described PoS set `[_PRT_, _NOUN_, ...]` (findable [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info))

Doing this I obtain sum figures that are 1/3rd of the one I'd get from the displayed dataframe above. Which strenghthen my hypothesis above that one count will account three times. But I can't help persuading myself what the best way to do it is, especially notifying these weird tokens `,_.`, `._.`, `_._` which meanings I don't have any clue.

Comment: I'm stuck too. Did you ever find the official list of PoS tags? i am not seeing weird tokens but i see _X and _. for PoS tags which I don't understand. The weird tokens that you are seeing are not PoS tags but actual strings from the corpus. You can ignore them by ignoring the _punctuation.gz files from the raw ngram data.

Comment: The full list of PoS tags is described after "The full list of tags is as follows:" on the Google link https://books.google.com/ngrams/info

Comment: thank you very much, that's perfect! :-)

Comment: also comparing notes with your question: i have been analyzing the chinese ngram data and i find the same weird tokens `_._`, `,_.` etc. It helps to know that they are also in the english dataset and not just strange chinese characters. Do you think that they are just periods and commas in some weird format?

Comment: You're welcome ! Well, it must be linked, sure... Especially in my above example `equal ,` and `equal ,_.` both have 2276119 counts, so one is like a superset of the other probably. Same for `equal .` and `equal ._.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of POS tags given in the [documentation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info) does not mention two of the tags, but the [2012 paper *Syntactic Annotations for the Google Books Ngram Corpus*](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/38277.pdf) does:

- `‘.’` (punctuation marks)
- `X` (a catch-all for other categories such as abbreviations or foreign words)

So the token `,_.` is a comma appended with its POS tag, just like the token `run_VERB`. Similarly, `._.` is a full stop appended with its POS tag. Finally, `_._` means punctuation, any punctuation just like `_VERB_` is any verb.

Comment: Haha, well catch! Thanks for the excavation